# Create login and logout loop in Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to *create* a login and logout loop that I've had

to [www.shopee.com.my](http://www.shopee.com.my)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
import urllib.parse

url = 'https://shopee.com.my/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('E:/users/Asashin/Desktop/Bots/others/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

actions = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
time.sleep(1)

lan=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="English"]')
if lan.is_displayed:
    lan.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)

ads=driver.find_element_by_class_name('shopee-popup__close-btn')
if ads.is_displayed:
    ads.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)

time.sleep(2)


firstLevelMenu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="navbar__links"]')
actions.move_to_element(firstLevelMenu).perform();

secondLevelMenu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[contains(text(), "Login")]');
secondLevelMenu.click();

time.sleep(3)
f= open("account.csv","r")

for line in f :
      fields = line.split(",")

      a = fields[0]
      b = fields[1]
      c = fields[2]

      driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']").send_keys(str(a))
      driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']").send_keys(str(c))
      time.sleep(0.8)

      button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="_1BMmPI _37G57D _7h_6kj _1qIIqG _3JP5il"]')
      if button.is_displayed:
          button.click()
          time.sleep(2)
      else:
          continue

      time.sleep(1)

      ads2=driver.find_element_by_class_name('shopee-popup__close-btn')


      if ads2.is_displayed:
          ads2.click()
          time.sleep(0.5)
      try:
          banned = driver.switch_to_alert.text("Your account has been banned")
          banned2 = driver.switch_to_alert.text("Invalid Email")

          if banned.is_displayed():
            while True:
                  q= open ('Banned Accounts.txt',w)
                  File_object.write(a)

                  driver.get_element_by_class_name('input-with-status__input').clear()
                  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']").clear()
          continue
      except:
          browser.driver.close();
```

Here are the account names and password:

[image]

The thing is that I've tried the hover method, but it doesn't seem to work. The div class is made of a hovering method and the drop-down menu will only happen together with the logout menu.

How can it be solved?

Comment: Can you include the `html` for the page?

Comment: @brydenr its www.shopee.com.my

Answer (score 0):

So far from what I understand you have problem with logging out.

Maybe you hovered to the wrong element. Or tried to click `Logout` div before it appeared.

Once I logged in, this code was enough for me to log out (after closing all pop ups)

```py
account_div = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//li[contains(@class, "navbar__link--account")]//div[contains(@class, "navbar__link-text")]'
)
#
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(account_div).perform()

logout_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[text()="Logout"]')
logout_button.click()
```

Once more tip. Instead of using sleep it's better to set once `driver.implicitly_wait`

So for example if you set `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` and you want to find an element by XPath it will wait up till five seconds before raising an error. It helps to save time as you don't need to explicitly wait `n` seconds.